# Highlighting all compilation errors in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a good way to highlight all compilation errors in emacs, specifically in haskell-mode?

The function `next-error` (<kbd>C-x  `</kbd>) highlights only a single error, but it doesn't set `match-data` to the error, at least in `haskell-mode`, with its `haskell-interactive-mode-next-error`. Even less helpfully, it calls `(error "No more errors")` at the last error, so I think maybe it is only meant to be called interactively.

I did the following to create highlight overlays at every compilation error, but it is really clunky and unreliable. `next-error-function` is supposed to be defined by the compilation mode (`haskell-interaction-mode` in my case); on return, match-data seems to point to some string. I use the variable `compilation-highlight-overlay` to get the overlay that next-error creates.

```
(let (buf (just-started t) errors overlays)
     ;; Ask next-error to create all the highlighting overlays, save
     ;; their locations, then delete them, use the locations to
     ;; create our own overlays.
     (ignore-errors
       (when (setq buf (next-error-find-buffer))
         (save-match-data
           (save-excursion
             (dotimes (max-iter 10)
               (with-current-buffer buf
                 (funcall next-error-function 1 just-started)
                 (setq just-started nil)
                 (let* ((o compilation-highlight-overlay)
                        (start (overlay-start o)) (end (overlay-end o)))
                   ;; (message "Found (%s,%s)" start end)
                   (push (cons start end) errors)
                   (push o overlays))))))))
     (mapc 'delete-overlay overlays)
     (dolist (err errors)
       (let ((o (make-overlay (car err) (cdr err))))
         (overlay-put o 'category 'error-highlight))))
```

Is there some kind of canonical way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to exploit `next-error-function` to find all errors, because it is implemented in very imperative fashion.

I have started a tiny project called `complation-highlight-el` that enables us to see more than one error at the same time.

https://github.com/m2ym/compilation-highlight-el

Still experimental stage, feel free to submit issues.